# What can i use to stop my military boots from squeeking on tile floors?

Tags: shoes

Kids keep laughing and it sucks having to deal with that in highschool,so what can I do?

Comment: Lots of wax on the soles. Then you can laugh at everyone else for having to walk while you smugly glide past in style!

Answer (score 1):

It's not your boots. It's the wax they use on industrial floors. Most good quality clean boots will squeak on these polished floors. I would find another boot, and put adhesive cloth on the bottom of the soles. Wear these at the fancy places (indoors).., wear your other boots when needed.

If you just wear you boots at high school halls, well, put duct tape on the soles, it wears out and stops the squeak by adding friction (at first you slide, then that part wears out and then there's friction).

It's the sound of rubber being rubbed against a freshly waxed industrial floor.

Answer (score 0):

If nobody forces you to wear these particular boots, you could get a different (more comfortable) pair of shoes to wear while you are at school.

In case you are madly in love with those boots, you can keep the second pair in a locker/backpack/car .. (Though my gutfeeling/highschool experience tells me that changing the shoes at school just for the looks might invite mockery again. Nature of kids everywhere since forever? ;) )

Comment: If these are uniform boots because OP is in the military, your solutions won't work, NTM, kinda ugly having duct tape on them. You can use a regular bar of soap and rub the dry bar over the soles several times. Repeat if necessary. Carry a travel size bar of soap in your pocket or bag.